# Web Server Performance based on CPU

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache, amazon-web-services

I have web server with ubuntu 12.04 64bit. While doing some heavy stress testing with jmeter on application that's at that server, I noticed that I'm starting to reach server capabilities. I'm using amazon aws and I can increase server CPU/RAM. So my question is this, would increasing CPU help with performance? If so, what apache/mysql config parameters should I increase? I thought to increase mysql/apache max connections, but mysqltuner shows me that I'm not fully using all connections (currently mysql is set to 500 max connections).

Some other info about server:

- PHP 5.3.1 with APC
- MySQL 5.5.35. 3 MyISAM tables, 1 InnoDB table.
- Apache 2.2 with prefork.

Since I'm using Redis to store most of my data, mysql database is really small, so I don't think increase mysaim/innodb buffers would help. That's why I think tuning Apache parameters should help.

Apache prefork config:

```
StartServers       100
MinSpareServers    75
MaxSpareServers    100
ServerLimit       500
MaxClients        500
MaxRequestsPerChild  5000

MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
```

Current amazon server: CPU 8 cores, 16 GB RAM. Available server: 16 Cores, 24 GB RAM.

Any thoughts/advices really appreciated, as it would save me time that I would spend on testing new server.

Comment: This would probably get better feedback on http://serverfault.com/ it isn't really programming related.

Comment: With low database access, its unlikely you will run out of connections  on the db side. If you are running into issues with your Apache config, you will often see errors in the log files related to not having enough servers running.

Comment: Is it possible to move this question to serverfault.com? And datavase access is supposed to be high, ~2k concurrent users trying to login (accessing one same table at the same time).